# How to correctly style GEOJSON (ESRI shapefile) for Geoserver?

Tags: geoserver, style, features

I have a geojson file, where features are styled - fill and stroke colours - like this:

```
{"type":"Feature"
,"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[15.50487,50.72638],....,15.50487,50.72638]]]}
,"style":{
      "stroke":"#FF0000",
      "stroke-opacity": 1.0,
      "fill":"#FB7F7F",
      "fill-opacity":0.8
 }
}
```

I convert the file to shp format using ogr2org like this:

```
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" as.shp as.geojson -nlt POLYGON -skipfailures
```

When I create a layer using the shp file, all features are displayed in grey although the style specified in original geojson is shown in table below the Geoserver preview map (see the picture for the detail).

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: A shapefile has no style, the style depends on the software used.

Comment: I am using Geoserver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the properties of the file in your sld file to set all the values that you require.

```
<sld:stroke >
 <CSSParameter name = 'stroke'>
 <ogc:propertyName>stroke </ogc:propertyName>
</CSSParameter >
</sld:stroke >
```

Comment: Sorry, I am new to Geoserver and the whole Gis technology - could you be more specific? I tried tutorial from Geoserver, which loads NYC roads and they has colours although the come from shape file as well.

Comment: I quickly went through SLD doc under Geoserver - it's more clear now, but I cannot find a way, how to assign a style to one specific shape (feature) in my SHP file - simply - now I want a feature to be green filled and next time, when I regenerate the SHP file, I want the same feature to be blue - is there a way, how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe it's doable out of the box given than your shapefile still contains all the styling bits as a JSON string inside an attribute.

Either find a way to split them into separate columns with a further conversion, and then you'll be able to follow Ian's advice, or write a new filter function that can parse JSON and extract properties out of it, and then use it in your SLDs.
See: http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/tutorial/function.html